# ruby refactoring cheatsheet?

Tags: ruby

is there any free cheatsheet on ruby refactoring that i can print and put on the wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your talking about taking common [code smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smells) and refactoring them. I haven't seen anything ruby specific, but most of what I've seen can be applied to any object oriented language if you know the [basic concepts of OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Fundamental_concepts).

Try [Smells to Refactorings](http://www.industriallogic.com/papers/smellstorefactorings.pdf) which is a two page quick reference which describes code smells and then lists refactoring methods that can be used to fix them. To get a description (along with code samples in Java) of each of these refactoring methods, check out the [Refactorings Catalog](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/) on Martin Fowler's page.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of Ruby refactoring do you want to do?  I think this question needs to be cleared up a little bit.

Otherwise, for a Ruby refactoring tool, you can check out: [Rfactor](http://github.com/fabiokung/rfactor/tree/master)

Comment: +1 nice. never used Rfactor, maybe you can share your experiences with it. Do you use it within the editor or separately on the command line?